# How do I plot multiple probability distributions side-by-side in R?

Tags: r, statistics

I want to plot several probability distributions side-ways (density on the x-axis, variable on y-axis). Each distribution will be associated with a different category, and I want them side-by-side so that I can compare between them. This is a bit like a box-plot but instead I want an theoretical probability distribution that I will specify giving parameters. So if they were all normal distributions, I would simply provide the mean and std deviation for each. Thanks.

Comment: Would that be PDFs for a family of distributions or several families? Have you tried code from this page? http://www.statmethods.net/advgraphs/probability.html

Answer (score 2):

do you mean something like this?

```
 x <- seq(-10, 10, length=100)
 normal.dist <- dnorm(x, 0, 2)
 f.dist <- df(x, 3, 4)
 t.dist <- dt(x, 3)
 chi.dist <- dchisq(x,3)
 par(mfrow=c(2,2))
 plot(x, normal.dist, type='l', lty=1 )
 plot(x, f.dist, type='l', lty=1, xlab="x value", col='blue')
 plot(x, t.dist, type='l', lty=1, xlab="x value", col='red')
 plot(x, chi.dist, type='l', lty=1, xlab="x value", col='green')
```

see also Roman  Luštrik's very helpful link as well as the helfiles (e.g. `?dnorm`).

[image]

**Rotated axis**

```
 x <- seq(-10, 10, length=100)
 normal.dist <- dnorm(x, 0, 1)
 normal.dist2 <- dnorm(x, 0, 2)
 normal.dist3 <- dnorm(x, 0, 3)
 normal.dist4 <- dnorm(x, 0, 4)


 par(mfrow=c(2,2))
 plot(normal.dist, x, type='l', lty=1 )
 plot(normal.dist2, x, type='l', lty=1, col='red' )
 plot(normal.dist3, x, type='l', lty=1, col='green' )
 plot(normal.dist4, x, type='l', lty=1, col='blue' )
```

[image]

Comment: I wanted something similar but with the normal distributions rotated. Thanks for the answer though.

Comment: It's easy enough to fix. Just swap the first two arguments `plot( f.dist, x, type='l', lty=1, ylab="x value", col='blue')` and relabel axes.

Answer (score 1):

You can set up a frame for plot display and specify how many plots you want to show in a frame using par(mfrow()), for example:

```
par(mfrow=c(2,2))
plot(first plot)
plot(second plot)
hist(third histogram)
boxplot(fourth boxplot)
```

See the following link for the full description:
http://www.statmethods.net/advgraphs/layout.html